# node js on azure - deeply nested node modules cause error

Tags: node.js, npm, azure-web-app-service, lodash

I'm using a node module called swagger-tools, which internally depends on lodash. When swagger tools is installed, the depth of its node_modules folder is very big, which causes an error on my azure web app (a Windows server). I saw somewhere that this problem can be solved by using npm 3, and while npm 3 is installed on azure server, I can't force it to use it - the error logs indicate that npm 2 is being used. This is how I do it in package.json:

```
"engineStrict": true,
"engines" : {
  "npm" : ">=3.0.0"
}
```

The node version is 4.4.7.
If anyone knows about a different way to fix the issue I will be glad.

Answer (score 0):

you are correct that NPM 3 should solve the issue because it uses flat file system and not nested dependencies in which windows file system doesn't support well.
To force NPM 3 it really depends on your publish method (git/vs). 
Here is a guide for forcing NPM 3 - 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2015/09/13/npm3-on-azure-web-apps/

Answer (score 0):

Set the npm path to the absolute location to the npm 3 on Azure Web Apps file system in [Custom Deployment Script](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Custom-Deployment-Script) as described by @shachar will be a solution.

And additionally, there is a easier workaround. You can define the nodejs version in your `package.json` to the version which contains the npm 3. The lowest nodejs version which contains npm3 is `5.0.0`.

So, you can simply modify the `engines` section in your `package.json`:

```
"engines" : {
  "node" : "5.0.0"
}
```

You can refer https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/nodejs-specify-node-version-azure-apps/ for more info.